# Memory usage of session copy of application variable In Visual Basic 6 COM

Tags: memory-management, multidimensional-array, com, vb6, global-variables

I believe that I had not drafted my question clearly enough in my previous posting.

My question relates to the old technology. Yet it matters a lot to me to get a through answer. Could a Visual Basic expert answer me or include links to other sites and sheds light on this memory usage question please?

Consider the following VB 6 code in a custom COM plus object on a page on an e-commerce site:

Assign long and short strings to the globalArray elements. Also some of the elements of globalArray hold smaller arrays.

And also load the xml:

```
Dom globalArray(30, 100000) 
Set objGlobalDom = CreateObject("msxml2.FreeThreadedDomDocument.6.0")
objGlobalDom.loadXML (xmlStr) 
Application.lock 
    Set Application(“objGlobalDom”) = objGlobalDom 
    Application(“globalArray”) = globalArray 
Application.unlock
```

With any new session the following variable assignments are done:

```
set Session(“objGlobalDom”) = Application(“objGlobalDom”) 
session(“globalArray”) = Application(“objGlobalDom”)
```

The Application(“objGlobalDom”) will contain an xml with some 1000 nodes and each node takes about 3k of memory. The array will take some 50 meg of memory.

Considering VB6 and COM object:

I understand that each instance of the object references the object’s data. What I don’t understand is:

1- If Session(“objGlobalDom”) does not contain a copy of the Application(“objGlobalDom”), why changes in the data of Session(“objGlobalDom”) are not automatically reflected in the data of Application(“objGlobalDom”) or does the Session(“objGlobalDom”) have a copy of the Application(“objGlobalDom”)?

2- According to Microsoft, in a situation such as my globalArray example, the Session(“globalArray”) always gets a copy of the Application(“globalArray”) and so Microsoft discourages assigning the array to session variables. But it is not clear to me that in the case of COM object and object references, does the assignment of set Session(“objGlobalDom”) = Application(“objGlobalDom”) copies the array to the session variable?

I really appreciate your answers and thank you in advance for your response.

Comment: Thank you for your response.
Although I knew about object references, my confusion continues with respect to the data portion of the object. 
How is it that the modifications to the data of the session variable are not automatically reflected to the data in the application variable although the data of a modified session variable is a reference to the data of application variable? Or if what we modify in session variable is not the actual data in the application variable then what do we modify in the session variable? How the session variable is not taking extra memory for the data?
Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual basic COM memory usage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33762312/visual-basic-com-memory-usage)

Answer (score 0):

COM Object are just UDT 'User Defined Type' (structs int c, record in delphi). that hold pointers to function, and private data related for each instance of the object.

when you see in VB the keyword `set` it does not mean it will copy all data from var to var, it just copy its reference (address) and add one to the refcount of that object. and when you do test var=nothing the object will not be freed until refcount reach 0. So set Obj=Nothing decrements Object RefCount , and if RefCount =0 the the Object Free Itself.