# Visual Basic COM memory usage

Tags: arrays, memory-management, com, vb6

My question relates to the old technology. Yet it matters a lot to me to get a thorough answer. Could a Visual Basic expert answer me or include links to other sites and sheds light on this memory usage question please? I believe that I had not drafted my question clearly enough in my previous posting.

Consider the following VB 6 code in a custom COM plus object on a page on an e-commerce site:

```
Dim globalArray(30, 100000) 

'Assign long and short strings to the globalArray elements.
'Also some of the elements of globalArray hold smaller arrays. And also load the xml:

Set objGlobalDom = CreateObject("msxml2.FreeThreadedDomDocument.6.0") 
objGlobalDom.loadXML (xmlStr)
Application.lock
Set Application("objGlobalDom") = objGlobalDom
Application("globalArray")  = globalArray
Application.unlock
```

With any new session the following variable assignments are done:

```
set Session("objGlobalDom") =  Application("objGlobalDom")
session("globalArray") = Application("objGlobalDom")
```

Let's suppose that the `Application("objGlobalDom")` will contain an xml with some 1000 nodes and each node takes about 3k of memory. Let’s say the array will take some 50 meg of memory.

Considering VB6 and COM object:

1. I understand that each instance of the object references the object’s data.
   What I don’t understand is:
   If `session("objGlobalDom"`) does not contain a copy of the `application("objGlobalDom")`, why changes in the data of `session("objGlobalDom")` are not automatically reflected in the data of `application("objGlobalDom")`?  Is the reference of `session("objGlobalDom")` to `Apllication("globalDom")` only for reading the data of `Application("objGlobalDom")`?
2. According to Microsoft, in a situation such as my `globalArray` example, the `session("globalArray")` always gets a copy of the `Application("globalArray")` and so Microsoft discourages assigning the array to session variables. But it is not clear to me that in the case of COM object and object reference, does the assignment of `set Session("objGlobalDom") = Application("objGlobalDom")` copies the array to the session variable?

Comment: I'm not sure if this fully answers your question, but https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/243548 seems to explain why you should not be doing this, in particular under the third bullet.

Comment: Thank you for trying to answer my question. Although your link provides some useful information it does not have any references to memory usage of session copy of application level object variables. If you have any other information I will be happy to receive it.

Comment: It explains right there: *avoid using module level variables in .bas modules, because **each thread has its own copy** and only objects or requests on the same thread can share them. From an application’s perspective, this causes unpredictable behavior because each user request can potentially be handled by a different thread, which would **contain a different value** for the variable*.

Comment: My question is not about module level variables it is about session copy of application object variables. If you think the

Comment: If you think I am missing some concept here please explain it to me. Thank you.

Comment: A session storage is effectively a global variable. VB objects use single-threaded apartment, which means they cannot be used from another thread. So the runtime will split the storage to provide a different instance for each thread.

Comment: In my example I use FreeThreadedDomDocument which is not single threaded apartment.  Could you tell me how your explanation with single threaded apartment relates to it?

Comment: Also I really don't grasp what you

Comment: Sorry for broken text. I really don't grasp what you mean by runtime will split storage. Do you mean that runtime will take new memory space for each session variable? And how about the array assignments within com object and memory usage ? I would really appreciate it if you could clarify these confusions for me. And just to be clear, I am not assigning com objects to application and session varaibles. I assign the FreeThreadedDomDocument to application and session variables.

Comment: The Visual Basic runtime treats all VB objects as single-threaded. The `msxml2` is not designed exclusively for VB, it can be used from any COM-compatible environment, including the ones that truly support threads, which is why it has a `FreeThreadedDomDocument`. The VB runtime has no way to understand that this particular object is safe to access from multiple threads, and does not try to do so. Therefore each thread will always receive its own copy of any global variables.

Comment: Thank you. So in that case, what is the reason that while Microsoft suggests not to assign apartment threaded objects variables to application and session, it suggests to assign free threaded objects to application and session variables? Is microsofts suggestion irrelevant to memory usage?

Comment: Sorry. A previous response was:"COM Object are just UDT 'User Defined Type' (structs int c, record in delphi). that hold pointers to function, and private data related for each instance of the object. when you see in VB the keyword set it does not mean it will copy all data from var to var, it just copy its reference (address) and add one to the refcount of that object. and when you do test var=nothing the object will not be freed until refcount reach 0. So set Obj=Nothing decrements Object RefCount , and if RefCount =0 the the Object Free Itself." Do you confirm this?

Comment: Yes, and this is related to COM in general, not COM in VB in particular. However it seems rather unrelated to your question.

Comment: Everybody knows how bad it is to often lock an application var for modifying it. In order to finish this subject, do you know if it is a bad practice to often access an application var in every session for reading? What side effects are there for repeatedly reading an application var? Thank you